# Is it possible to sync user information that exposed by oAuth to clients?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, synchronization, user-profile

The problem is the following:

I have a web application (A) that allows users to use it as oAuth on other third party apps (B and C). Let's assume that some user is already authenticated in third party apps and then update some data (like first name and last name) in the main app (A). Is it possible for apps B and C to know about these changes and sync data?

Comment: Yes of course, if you provide the API in A to do so, and then use that API from B and C.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten at the current moment I'm thinking about providing some endpoint url (like callback url) that I can use to notify B an C about user updates on A

Comment: There are two basic ways to solve this problem. The simplest is that B and C simply do not store user profile information, but get it from A every time they need it. Modifications are then stored in A. The other option is that applications like B and C tell A about a callback that A should call whenever data is updated. Both options are viable. So if you want to go for the callback mechanism, what is preventing you to do so?

Comment: @KrisVandermotten nothing, just thinking about it and trying to find out other options :) Thank you for your thoughts